# Framework for educational site and forum with single database

Tags: frameworks, programming-languages, forum

I'm newbie in back-end development, that's why I want to start learning not from pure coding but choosing framework. Want to understand, how it works and start writing unique code by myself.

I've tried to choose framework basing on my future project and couldn't do it without the qualified help. I've searched before to write here, but couldn't find all I need. I don't ask for deep pieces of advice, manuals or so here. Hope, that you as more experienced can show me few ways and I'll choose the one by myself.

What I need to do with framework capabilities:

1. Forum:

   - one (or crossing) users' database with site
   - one header and footer for forum and site
   - changeble design themes (full CSS support)
   - groups' rights and design
   - user's rights and design
   - moderators, admins, plain users
   - forum sections, that could be nested
   - themes
   - visual post formatting
   - images inserting
   - symbols counting in posts
   - symbols counting for each user in theme
2. Site:

   - same to forum users, their groups and rights
   - user profile with settings
   - guest book
   - education module: timetable by user group, courses with lessons, homework sending/discussing, homework statuses, marks/journal of all users and user groups, educational statistics for user groups
   - public user profile with text form data and all marks, forum activity, statuses and other information
   - autoposting some data from user profile to forum and updating it when changing the profile
   - inactivation/activation/ban for user accounts
   - IP viewing for admins: can see, what users/forum's messages have the same IP
   - messenger: private chats, private and public chat groups, auto-adding users to chats by users' group
   - private user notes, that are visible only for admins
   - bonus accrual
   - store, when users can change bonuses for virtual goods and session of playing game for random gifts
   - visual map, where everyone can see all forum sections and what users are on them
   - plain newspaper: issues with structured articles (a la usual blog posts), commenting for users, offering article feature

I know, that it's so much, but project is mine. And it can be developing for a long time. If I need to study a year or few, it's okay.

How do you think, what frameworks have the most of modules for described functional? Please, don't argufy. Write here if you had experience (or you know somebody who had) of realising features, that're described above.

Programming language doesn't matter (because I'm noob in all of them), but I think about Ruby and PHP (and PHPBB forum). Others are ok too, if them can afford what I need.

Sorry if I unknowingly said something wrong. Tell me and I'll fix it.

Comment: this is completely based on your requirement. This is too broad  to be addressed here

Comment: You mean, that any language and any framework will be effective in same way in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wanting to build a lot for someone that knows nothing about any languages.

First you need to pick a platform/OS..   Windows or Unix/Linux?

From there, you can pick a Web Server to run on based on that OS.

Then that filters out what kind of language your going to write with.

**EDIT**:
When someone wants to be a mechanic, do they go to each mechanic shop and ask what is the best car to work on?    Each mechanic would have a different answer.   No one here, will be able to give you a non-bias answer.  So here is what I like....

I write code in 18 languages and been have developed software for 25 years.   I've written code for DOS, Windows, and Linux/Unix.   Each language has it's own limitation and perfections, but I'm not a fan of open source and most Linux/Unix preferred languages even though some can run on Windows.  I have a tendency to lean towards windows and enjoy back end development.  I've written Web UIs in Angular, JSP, Java Spring Boot, WebFOCUS and ASP Classic.  Now that you know more about me, here are my favorites.

I prefer Windows.  I prefer C#.   If I have to build a web UI, I prefer HTML 5/CSS3/Javascript with an ASP.NET/C# backend.   I don't like bootstrap or jquery as I like to write with a small footprint as do most any older developer.  The internet is full of garbage that isn't being used by most every site you go to, just so the developer can get a few shortcuts.   Bootstrap and JQuery are just javascript libraries of which most sites can do what they want with 1/10 the code the client has to download, if they really knew Javascript.

There ya go, my bias opinion, take it or leave it, but most likely the only honest answer your going to get here.

Comment: It doesn’t mean, that I want all done in 1 day. I code on PHP for self and in SaaS as junior. Used GIT. Learned basic Ruby and Python. I just don’t know what to choose for effectivity. Because of that I described my aims in detail.

For developing I have a server cloud. There I can create Windows or Unix server, it doesn’t matter — I’ll choose what will be better.

Comment: Since the time of this post, I've written in over 30 languages.  ha.  I work for a large company, which only uses Java/Spring/Moneta Boot, and ReactJS.  All Linux.  I still prefer Windows and stable upgrades, because this open source is for the birds.   Upgrading on a weekly bases, dependency components that are 3-10 layers down, stop updating, so when you move to the next NodeJS v18, everything is broken and is taking me a week to resolve..  UGHH!!  ha.